# Flutter build Xcode: Module 'firebase_analytics' not found

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter

I tried to publish a new version of my app on the apple store and it gave this problem:

Module 'firebase_analytics' not found

Has anyone ever experienced this?

I found similar question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66748669/module-firebase-analytics-not-found) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66685348/flutter-fatal-error-module-firebase-analytics-not-found). but none of them helped to solve my issue.

[image]

Comment: Did you upgrade your firebase_core dependency? If yes, you should make a flutter clean before trying to create a new archive.

Comment: I tried this already, no luck

Comment: Do you have any errors when trying to make a pod install in the ios folder?

Comment: No errors, i can run app normally on simulator

Comment: issue when building

Comment: Hi. anyone solved this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, select Runner, then targets->Runner again Tab General, then put the value of the Deployment info 10.12 or up and see if builds.

[image]